# Transparent UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Am newbie to ios and I found this solution on making the UINavigationBar Transparent.
Where in my project files can I put this code

```
[self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

So that it is applied in my entire project where navigation controller is being used.

Comment: Ok.. What is your problem ?

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` or in your appDelegate file in `didFinishLunchWithOptions`

Comment: I pasted that code in my appDelegate but it is not making the navbar transparent.Is there something I should change? Sorry..Started learning ios :)

Comment: Maybe you have forget this `self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Comment: The app crashes when i introduce [UINavigationBar appearance].translucent = YES;

Error am getting is:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** Illegal property type, c for appearance setter, _installAppearanceSwizzlesForSetter:'

Comment: This is what i have in my appDelegate
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [UINavigationBar appearance].shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    [UINavigationBar appearance].translucent = YES;
When I run, the app crashes with this error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** Illegal property type, c for appearance setter, _installAppearanceSwizzlesForSetter:'

By use of breakpoint, It is pointing the error on setting translucent

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Put in your `viewDidLoad` function of your rootViewController this code:

## Objective-C:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

## Swift 2.x:

```
if let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar {
        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
        navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationBar.translucent = true
        navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
    }
```

## Swift 3:

```
if let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar {
        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        navigationController?.view?.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
```

This works for sure! [Transparent UINavigationBar](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6l6iltg9kwnwqx/Transparent-UINavigationBar.zip?dl=0).

Comment: This is what i have in my appDelegate
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [UINavigationBar appearance].shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    [UINavigationBar appearance].translucent = YES;
When I run, the app crashes with this error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** Illegal property type, c for appearance setter, _installAppearanceSwizzlesForSetter:'

By use of breakpoint, It is pointing the error on setting translucent

Comment: if i could give 5 more +1's then i would. this is a great solution

Comment: How to deactivate navbar transparency in next view when pushing

Comment: Just revert this using the same code but put the colour you prefer and set `translucent` to `NO`.

Comment: You just saved my tons of time. Thank you so much for the solution.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. All I get a gray status bar and a completely white navigation bar with nothing visible.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu did you check the example app?

Comment: @dimimpou yes. see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707190/how-to-make-uinavigationbar-background-transparent

Answer (score 2):

If you want change the appearance for all your application, I recommend you to use this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

hope that will help

Comment: I have tried that but it does not make it see through.

Answer (score 1):

In your UIViewController class. You can also use UIAppearance mechanism http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/

And place this

```
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [UINavigationBar appearance].shadowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Your image file here"];
```

into

```
- ( BOOL ) application:( UIApplication* ) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:( NSDictionary* ) launchOptions
```

Comment: The app crashes when i introduce this line [UINavigationBar appearance].translucent = YES;

Comment: Am getting this error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** Illegal property type, c for appearance setter, _installAppearanceSwizzlesForSetter:'

Comment: Yes, sorry. translucent is not appearance selector. You can find full list of appearance selectors here https://gist.github.com/mattt/5135521

Answer (score 0):

```
Transparent UIToolbar:
self.toolbar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(),
                                forToolbarPosition: UIBarPosition.Any,
                                barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.toolbar.setShadowImage(UIImage(),
                            forToolbarPosition: UIBarPosition.Any)
Transparent UINavigationBar:
self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

Answer (score -4):

set following code

```
Self.navigationcontroller.navigationbar.transculant=yes;
```