# UINavigationController transparency?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to get my navigation bar to become 100% transparent, so that the UINavigationButtonItems are only visible and the background (normally white) should show the background image.

I tried

```
HomeNavigationController *navBar = [[HomeNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.myViewController];
[navBar.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [navBar.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

although neither appear to work.

EDIT:

Using

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

I can see that it worked as expected, however the items are now also invisible.

---

FINALEDIT: Ah the code above DOES work, just ensure you do not apply any other changes to the appearance without testing first !

The code that actually does what is intended:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Alternatively you can set a transparent image, but this makes more sense. You will need the rest of the code shown in the original edit if you want no line representing the border.

Comment: you could try [navBar.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0];

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850622/transparent-uinavigationbar/21850947#21850947, maybe helps u.

Comment: If you need your UINavigationBar to be completely transparent, then why not hide it altogether, and use custom `UIButtons` instead of `UIBarButtonItems`?
The appearance of `UINavigationBars`, `UITabBars` and `UIToolbars` has changed with iOS 7 making it harder and probably not advisable to tinker with their transparency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a trick.
Just set transparent image to the navigation bar background.

```
UIImage *fakeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparentImage"];
[navigationBar setBackgroundImage:fakeImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

OR

```
[navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                    forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: You will also need to set the shadow image the same way to an empty `UIImage`.