# UINavigationBar transparent + on top of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a [transparent UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707190/how-to-make-uinavigationbar-background-transparent). I also set `hidesBarsOnSwipe` to true. I want my navigationBar be on top of the content and hides when scrolling. Basically i want to achieve this effect (Navigation Bar on top of the content and also hiddes when scroll):

[image]

For now i just have this code and works everything, but i'm not able to put the content of the view behind the navigationBar:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

[image]

[Here is a sample project](https://ufile.io/5l407) , as you see the tableView is at the bottom of the navigationBar and just goes to the top when it hides the navigationBar.

Comment: You can change color of navigation bar with tableview contentoffset if you need code please let me know.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

On your view controller in Interface Builder disable `Adjust Scroll View Insets`. You can probably do it from code if you want as well.