# How to remove navigation bar colour clear in swift4?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I want to clear color of navigation bar. In my ViewController there is a background image on that, when i remove color of navigation barTintColor, navigationController.view.background and navigation background image then simulator shows me :-
[image]

I have been trying alots of codes but there is no solution found. 
I want navigation Bar like that:-
[image]

with clear navigation bar color.
Is there any solution, let me know?
Thanks!

Comment: maybe this one helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/34767128/10150796

Comment: I think your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969823/5391914

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make the navigation bar transparent in `viewWillAppear` and remove transparency in `viewWillDisappear` as follows

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}
```

The background image and the back button will be visible

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Better you must avoid the navigation bar. Hide the navigation bar in the navigation controller and user custom view in your view controller to avoid this issue.

Comment: Thats not the solution.  You can write this in comment .

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5::** Calling below in AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function does the trick (This will be applied to your all navigationBars though, don't forget to switch your view controllers)

```
let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
navBarAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
            
navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
```