# Setting navigationBar to clear

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to set the Navigation Controller Navigation Bar to clear / opacity 0

I seem to have it somewhat working, when I run my code in the simulator the white background bar is there however if I navigate to my other page then back it disappears.

My code is the same as the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845855/transparent-navigation-bar-ios), yes but my issue is that the Nav Colour only works once I've navigated away from the first screen and gone back to it. It's not that it doesn't work completely.

```
import UIKit

class LoginMenuViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

    }    

}
```

Comment: @RajeshKumarR It's not a duplicate my issue is that the nav Colour changes once I've navigated away and back to the screen. Not that it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55627590/7250862

Comment: @RajeshKumarR thanks for that, I'm rather new to Swift so not quite sure where this would go. Is it for the view controller?

Comment: yes. Paste that code inside your view controller class

Comment: @RajeshKumarR still no look that makes it worse. If I navigate to the second screen then back again it's still white whereas before it was clear

Comment: If you navigate to the second screen then back again, viewWillAppear of first view controller is called?

Comment: Yes both functions run